# Sharing an Audio File to whatsapp is not supported

Tags: android, eclipse

I try to add a share button to my application where i can send an mp3 file to whatsapp but if i click they Show me this file is not supported

Here is my code

```
public void sharebutton1(View view){

        Intent share = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("audio/mp3");
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file:///"+R.raw.tst1));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

Comment: What is the extension of the file, If you can share it with us, that would be better

Comment: I am trying to share .mp4 extension file